# How can I establish TCP socket connection between android apps and delphi server?

Tags: java, android, delphi

I m having one question that is regarding to tcp socket communication between android apps & delphi server.

Is that possible to establish connection between android tcp client app and delphi tcp  server? If yes then how?

Comment: What have you tried? I don't know delphi, but I see no reason why you can't establish a TCP connection from an Android app to any platform. Open a socket, and start sending/receiving data.

Comment: You'd better add some details to that question *fast* because it's going to get closed. What have you tried, what do you know, what's giving you trouble. Do you know how to establish a TCP connection from either platform to any platform, or are you truly asking a yes/no question?

Answer (score 3):

There are several socket based libraries for Delphi that come in either Event or Thread based flavours. These include:

- [Indy](http://www.indyproject.org/index.en.aspx) - Thread based socket components
- [ICS](http://www.overbyte.be/frame_index.html?redirTo=/products/ics.html) - Async Event Based socket components

Either of the above can be used to implement a TCP Socket listener on your server to which Android can communicate.

I'd recommend an ASync based library like ICS if you are expecting a high number of concurrent connections as Thread based socket application consume on average a couple of MB per connection, which is instantiated on a separate thread.

- Indy TCPServer example [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/indy10clieservr/).
- ICS article to help you started [here](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20465).
- Android Java TCP Client example [here](http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/android-tcp-connection-tutorial.html).

Comment: Do you have any tests (source code) which show that ICS scales better than Indy? (just curious...) Memory allocation for threads can be adjusted, see http://www.deltics.co.nz/blog/?p=1297

Comment: My comment is based on personal observations based on event based vs threaded servers. i.e.: Apache(threaded) vs NginX(event) and personal experiences with NodeJS (a brutally fast event based API). Whether ICS benefits from this beyond being event based does depend on their implementation. That and threaded implementations require more memory due to the how Windows manages threads. Again, HTH.

Comment: Thank You .. I did not try from one platform to another.. Can u provide source code for TCP connection between delphi and android ?.

Comment: @Neerav Both Indy and ICS ship with several examples for running standalone TCP servers.

Comment: Updated answer with example links. HTH.